# WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions

Tags: numpy, gcc, theano, pymc3

I was trying to install pymc3 with Miniconda in Windows. The installation was certainly non-trivial and took me many hours of trouble-shooting to understand what is going on.

I have read many posts from different people on this question and found this guide to be quite helpful:

[pymc3 installation guide in Windows](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/4937)

After following through the steps recommended here, I still came across the warning when `importing pymc3 as pm` in a jupyter-notebook:

`WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.`

Below are some solutions that I have tested and did not work to remove this warning:

1. `conda install -c conda forge libpython blas mkl-service m2w64-toolchain` in addition to the packages bundled with pymc3 (`theano-pymc3` and `arviz`) in the first conda environment.
2. Downloaded GCC compiler and make sure it is on the global path in the correct order as suggested by the first guideline and the official guideline [Official pymc3 installation](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/wiki/Installation-Guide-(Windows)) in the second conda environment and installed without `m2w64-toolchain`.
3. I have also tried using the GCC compiler from Rtools and updated the path in the environment variable in the 3rd conda environment.

I think I have exhausted all the different options I have read and still didn't manage to remove this warning. Is there anything that I have missed out in trouble-shooting this warning?

I understand that this warning doesn't stop the computation, and would only affect the computational performance. Because I have quite a large dataset, I would certainly appreciate a feasible solution to fix this problem :)

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score -2):

According to https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/394033647
to create .theanorc.txt
may solve this problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).